# What does (Mb) Ncells 284.8 Vcells 459.9 mean in RStudio

Tags: ggplot2, average, summary, geom-col, arrange-act-assert

I used the function gc() when the RAM looks like it is going RED and the message that I received is Mb Ncells 284.8 and Vcells 459.9.

What does that mean, especially after I just saved 8GB of memory to RStudio with their $25.00 a month subscription plan.

Answer (score 0):

R, following [lisp language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_(programming_language)) heritage, is based on [S expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression). S expressions are a tree-like structure that can be represented with "lists". `list(1, 2, 3)` is a list of three numbers. List can also contain lists as in `list(1, list(3, 4), 5)`, forming a tree of lists. At lower level, lists can be seen as a [`cons`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons). A `cons` is a pair (data, other cons), list(1, othercons). Ncells are those `cons`. In R, `cons` are called Node cells (Ncells) (they are in fact slightly more complicated than that but it does not matter for the sake of basic explanation). `gc()` Ncells returns the number of `Ncells` used and the space occupied by them, expressed in Mb. `max used` gives the maximum usage reached during your current session.

`Vcells` are a special type of cells to hold more efficiently list of the same element type (aka vectors). `Vcells` reports the number of those cells and the space in Mb occupied by them.

`gc trigger` reports the thresholds when the next [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) will be run.

> the message that I received is Mb Ncells 284.8 and Vcells 459.9.

It means that you use 284.8 Mega bytes and 459.9 Mega bytes.

> 8GB of memory

[8GB = 8000 MB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Units_of_information#Systematic_multiples), that is a lot more than what you are using.